# How to apply filter on JSON response?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm getting the JSON response as below:-

```
{
   "links":{
      "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes"
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "type":"tenantFields",
         "id":1,
         "attributes":{
            "field_name":"firstName",
            "is_required":false,
            "is_sync_enabled":true
         },
         "relationships":{

         },
         "links":{
            "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes/1"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"tenantFields",
         "id":2,
         "attributes":{
            "field_name":"lastName",
            "is_required":false,
            "is_sync_enabled":true
         },
         "relationships":{

         },
         "links":{
            "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes/2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"tenantFields",
         "id":3,
         "attributes":{
            "field_name":"userTitle",
            "is_required":false,
            "is_sync_enabled":false
         },
         "relationships":{

         },
         "links":{
            "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes/3"
         }
      }
   ],
   "included":[

   ]
}
```

Before performing any operation, I need to apply the filter based on **is_sync_enabled** to **true** (ignore all from the array where the value for is_sync_enabled is false) and then read only the **field_name** attribute value from the filtered JSON data.

Please suggests, thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Would you mind adding your attemps to get the desired results ? Please

Comment: I'm not good in JavaScript. But tried my luck in parsing the response by like this                 const attributeResponse = await getAttributesList(event, region, lambdaAttributeFunction);
                console.log('attributeResponse::', attributeResponse);

                var json = [];
                var resObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attributeResponse));
                 for (var id in resObj) {
                     if (resObj[id].name == 'data') {
                         json.push(resObj[id]);
                     }
                 }
                 console.log(json);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired output.

We'd use Array.filter to get the desired elements, looking for those with attributes *and* attributes with the .is_sync_enabled property set.

We can then use Array.map to pick the attributes.field_name property.

```js
let input = { "links":{ "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes" }, "data":[ { "type":"tenantFields", "id":1, "attributes":{ "field_name":"firstName", "is_required":false, "is_sync_enabled":true }, "relationships":{ }, "links":{ "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes/1" } }, { "type":"tenantFields", "id":2, "attributes":{ "field_name":"lastName", "is_required":false, "is_sync_enabled":true }, "relationships":{ }, "links":{ "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes/2" } }, { "type":"tenantFields", "id":3, "attributes":{ "field_name":"userTitle", "is_required":false, "is_sync_enabled":false }, "relationships":{ }, "links":{ "self":"https://xyz/v1/test/1/attributes/3" } } ], "included":[ ] };

let output = input.data.filter(element => {
    return (element.attributes && element.attributes.is_sync_enabled);
}).map(element => { 
    return element.attributes.field_name;
});

console.log("Output:", output);
```